# Reactjs vs backend data provider, best practice?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs, rest

I have been wondering, many tutorial I read about reactjs + backend such as php laravel. The controller call the view file and it render the html + javascript containing all the reactjs component but then it calls a **REST api** to get the "*initial data*".

What if the initial datas are rendered first hand at the top?

```
<script>
    var products = <?php echo json_encode($products) ?>;
    var reviews = <?php echo json_encode($reviews) ?>;
</script>
```

Is it a bad practice? I thought that would prevent additional ajax connection to the server. Or do I have to consider refactoring in the future if lets say backend change to java?

Thanks.

Comment: usually such webapps provide empty templates for the browsers. Once the browser has downloaded the sources, it will make a http request to recieve data. This is the common way imo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building an SPA, then doing that would just pollute the dom needlessly. You'll be making many subsequent api requests so fetching the initial data via the api is the right way to go. It's a difference of maybe a couple requests.

As progressive web apps gain in popularity and usage a common architecture is the App Shell. Basically the skeleton of the site with no data.

Comment: regarding API, one request for all needed data or granular API(each API for each type of data)?  Lets say page like amazon.com main page, they have main sliding banner, best seller item, deals item, so its better to have 1 api to provide all those data or create 3 separate API?

Comment: I just opened the amazon.com homepage and according to the network inspection tab in  dev tools, 289 total requests were made. Most of those were images and other static assets but I think it's safe to assume 1 request per data grouping. That is just a very generalized summary though as each situation will have it's unique needs.

Comment: I realized that SPA can actually handles all route in front-end, so Laravel only load the initial single index.php view file, the rest of routings are left to Reactjs, does this mean all components from different pages (main page, deal page, product detail, cart, checkout, thank you page, etc) must be preload by client browser first? Otherwise where it knows the html/css resource if it no longer hit the server (except for only data json).